# How to detect a collider and stop moving in that direction?

Tags: unity-game-engine, collision

I want my cube to detect a collider on all sides and stop moving in that direction
As seen in the image A and B are hindering the path of my cube
I want to achieve something like: If I press W I want my object to stay still and not move but If I press D it should move to the right because there is no obstacle there
How do I do this? I know how to detect objects using Raycasting but I cant compute if they are in front, back left or right side of my cube?

[image]

Comment: "I know how to detect objects using Raycasting" No you don't, you still need to learn that when you raycast you do so in a particular *direction*. Directions for your case are trivial: `Vector3.Up, Down, Left `etc.

Comment: I don't understand the problem.  The objects have colliders, the cube will hit the boxes and stop moving.

Comment: The object doesnt stop moving. the cube tries to go through them and creates a jittery effect

Comment: @user2347960 does your cube have a rigid body component?

Comment: yes it does but im not using physics to move my object 
I donot know how to 
I want to achieve a tumbling cube effect 
I want it to rotate 90 degrees in the direction of the button I press
I donot know how to do it except using RotateAround

Answer (score 0):

You may raycast in all 4 directions. For "W", only [Vector3.Forward](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3-forward.html) is needed. `Vector3.Up` is global up. `Vector3.forward` is "up" when viewing the scene from above. `Vector3.right` is self explainatory.

Note: What would happen when you press "W" & "D" at the same time? ;) If you go 45° up-right you may have another problem.

So in the end I suggest you do 8 raycasts in all directions.

For Debugging I suggest you use [Debug.DrawLine](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Debug.DrawLine.html)

If that sounds too complicated, why not scratch `raycasts` and just use a `rigidbody` + `collider`? Other `colliders` need to be non-trigger. That will stop your player without any `raycasts`.

Comment: Im sorry, perhaps I didnt make it clear enough
I have a cube that tumbles
It doesnt just move as is. It rotates 90 degrees each time I press a button
You can see the effect in this video 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sibXfMIJUPM
The problem is that I raycast from each face of the cube 
And while the raycast returns true when it hits an obstacle I donot know which side of the cube, the obstacle is placed at

Comment: Then just use `Vector.forward` (which is global direction) like I suggested, instead of `transform.forward` (this would be local, depending on cube orientation)

Comment: Thanks,man I will 
Iam making a game in which the player controls a cube which tumbles 
Am i moving in the right direction? Im not using physics to rotate or move my object . Is it the RIGHT way of doing things.I can even show you the script if you have the time to read it?

Comment: sure, attatch it and I will have a look.